# Application of the definition of enthalpy in a modified way

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

My book gave me this equation at constant temperature and constant volume:

$$\ce{2NH3(g) -> N2(g) + 3H2(g); \Delta U = 92.3 kJ}$$

And it says here enthalpy and internal energy are the same as volume is constant. But I have a thought that its pressure is not constant and hence enthalpy change will be different, because enthalpy by definition is 
\begin{align}
\mathrm dH &= \mathrm dU + \mathrm d(pV) \\
\mathrm dH &= \mathrm dU + \mathrm d(nRT)
\end{align}

For this equation we will get:

$$\Delta H = 92.3\ \mathrm{kJ} + 2RT$$

Am I correct with my thinking? If not, why?

Comment: You're correct, the book is wrong. $\Delta(pV) = p_2V_2 - p_1V_1$ and if $V_2 = V_1$, the $\Delta(pV)$ term reduces to $V(p_2 - p_1)$, which is not equal to zero unless $p_2 = p_1$ also.